# find coefficients of a numerical integration formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

we have this formula for calculating integral
$\int_{0}^{h} xf(x) dx = (h)^2 [A_0 f(0) + A_1f(h) + A_2f(2h)] + R \\$
the goal is to find $A_0,A_1, A_2$ and $R$, when $f^{\prime\prime\prime}$ is constant.

I tried to get to this formula by taking integral of Taylor Expansion of $xf(x)$ but it didn't work, or I messed up in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third derivative $f$ being constant means that $f$ is a cubic, so let $f(x)=ax^3+b^2x+cx+d$.  Plug that into your equation.  The result needs to be true for all $a,b,c,d$.  You will get simultaneous equations for $A_0,A_1,A_2$.  Note that $f(x)=0$ tells us that $R=0$.  It will fail because you have four equations in three unknowns.

Comment: so it's ok that for R to be 0? cause I did this too but I thought it's wrong :))

Comment: Yes, $R$ has to be $0$.  If it weren't, you could let $h$ go to zero and have the left be very small, smaller than $R$.  Some of the $A$s are $0$ in formulas like this as well.  There is no solution to the problem as stated.  You need one more point and one more $A$ on the right to make it work, or to demand that $f''(x)$ is constant so you only have a quadratic.